# window.pageYOffset not working with "height:100%"

Tags: css, scrollbar, css-transitions, google-web-designer

I want the scrollbar to move upward gently if user opens modal. I'm able to do that if I use `min-height:100%;` in my `<body>` tag but unable if I use `height:100%`. I want to do this with `height:100%` in the `<body>`. Can I do this?

Basically, `window.scrollY`, `window.pageYOffset` are giving correct values if I use `min-height:100%` but giving incorrect value i.e. `0` if I use `height:100%`. Anyone know how can I use `height:100%` and value `window.pageYOffset` together?